# Git: Your branch is ahead of 'staging' by 2 commits

Tags: git

I was on a branch 'staging'. On this basis, I created a branch 'tmp/carouse'. Changed several files and committed. 
Now

```
git status
```

says

```
# On branch tmp/small_carousel
# Your branch is ahead of 'staging' by 2 commits.
#
```

Is it OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. this means you have two commits which aren't in `staging` yet. This is just for informational purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You have made 2 commits to that branch that are not in the staging branch. Its just for information.

It allows you to keep track of how "developed" the small_carousel branch is as you will want to eventually merge it

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly acceptable in git. It means that you have committed twice to 'tmp/small_carousel' that has not been merged into 'staging'. Once you are ready to move all those changes into 'staging' you and switch to 'staging' and merge small_carousel into staging.